# How to run Java off of a FAT32 partition with Linux as the OS?

Tags: java, linux, fat32, partition

I have the same situation [as described here in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112371/launching-jre-in-linux-from-a-fat32-usb). Looks like, no solution was found.

I am additionally open to using OpenJDK if its build process / makefile can somehow be altered to yield a monolithic, statically-linked `java` binary, instead of one with loosely hanging `lib*.so`'s, which later have trouble being searched for or loaded by the loader.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shooting from the hip here, but is your FAT32 volume mounted with 'exec' option?

```
fdisk -l
mount -o exec /dev/sdc /media/usb
```

Comment: The `-o exec` option makes no difference, I get the same error regardless. `Error: could not find libjava.so . Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.`